# Jest Error thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test. Add a timeout value to this test to increase the timeout

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I tried to figure out why the test fails for the article.controller.js file.

thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
Add a timeout value to this test to increase the timeout, if this is a long-running test. See [https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout."](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout.%22)

```
  47 |   });
  48 |   describe("editArticle tests", () => {
> 49 |     test("If user can edit an article", async () => {
```

But, unable to find the cause of it.

In the `article.controller.js` file, for implementing article editing functionality, the article's slug is stored which in turn is used to call the `updateArticle` function. This function takes 3 arguments i.e, article's slug, logged in user's id and article object that is passed in the request payload.

```js
const {
  saveArticle,
  updateArticle,
  removeArticle,
  getArticle,
  getAllTags,
  getAllArticles,
  feedArticles,
  favoriteArticle,
  unFavoriteArticle,
} = require('../services/article.service');

exports.editArticle = async (req, res, next) => {
  const slugText = req.params.slug;
  if (slugText) {
    return updateArticle(slugText, req.user._id, req.body.article)
      .then((isUpdated) => {
        if (isUpdated) {
          return res.status(200).json({ article: isUpdated });
        }
      })
      .catch(next);
  }
};
```

To test the code for `editArticle` function, I defined `mockRequest` and `mockResponse` along with `mockUser`, `mockUpdatedArticle` objects. Then I added spy for `updateArticle` function which is being called when `editArticle` function is called. In the unit testing code I checked if the spied version for `updateArticle` is being called at least once and with proper arguments.

```js
const articleServiceHelper = require("../../../services/article.service");

const mockResponse = () => {
  return {
    status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    json: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()
  };
};

const mockNext = jest.fn();

const mockUser = {
  _id: "6368ad4347dkhs"
};

const mockUpdatedArticle = {
  title: "Updated article title",
  description: "Updated description",
  body: "Updated body"
}

describe("Unit tests for article.controller.js file", () => {
  describe("editArticle tests", () => {
    test("If user can edit an article", async () => {
      //Arrange
      const mockReq = { params: { slug: 'test-article-slug' }, user: { _id: "6368ad4347dkhs" }, body: { article: mockUpdatedArticle } };
      const mockRes = mockResponse();
      const updateArticleSpy = jest.spyOn(articleServiceHelper, "updateArticle").mockResolvedValue(mockUpdatedArticle);
      const { editArticle } = require("../../../controllers/article.controller");
      //Act
      const updatedArticle = await editArticle(mockReq, mockRes, mockNext);
      //Assert
      expect(updatedArticle).toBe(mockUpdatedArticle);
      expect(updateArticleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(updateArticleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockReq.params.slug, mockUser._id, mockReq.body.article);
      expect(mockRes.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200);
      expect(mockRes.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        article: mockUpdatedArticle
      });
      expect(mockNext).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Add a `console.log(updateArticle)` inside you `editArticle` function - if it logs anything other than `mockFunction`, then it's because it's not being mocked properly. It's possible you may have to require `editArticle` at the top level of your test, I'm not sure. But the first thing you should try it to verify that `updateArticle` is actually being mocked correctly inside your real `editArticle` function

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to fix my issue. I put **updateArticleSpy** outside of my test case. Also, changed the test code a little bit.

Below is the updated code for **article.controller.test.js** file.

```js
    const articleServiceHelper = require("../../../services/article.service");

    const mockResponse = () => {
      return {
        status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        json: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()
      };
    };

    const mockNext = jest.fn();

    const mockUser = {
      _id: "6368ad4347dkhs"
    };

    const mockArticle = {
      title: "Sample article title",
      description: "Sample article description",
      body: "Sample article body"
    }

    const mockUpdatedArticle = {
      title: "Updated article title",
      description: "Updated description",
      body: "Updated body"
    }
    const updateArticleSpy = jest.spyOn(articleServiceHelper, "updateArticle").mockResolvedValue(mockUpdatedArticle);
    describe("Unit tests for article.controller.js file", () => {
      describe("editArticle tests", () => {
        test("If user can edit an article", async () => {
          //Arrange
          const mockReq = { params: { slug: 'test-article-slug' }, user: { _id: "6368ad4347dkhs" }, body: { article: mockUpdatedArticle } };
          const mockRes = mockResponse();
          const { editArticle } = require("../../../controllers/article.controller");
          //Act
          await editArticle(mockReq, mockRes, mockNext);
          //Assert
          expect(updateArticleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
          expect(updateArticleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockReq.params.slug, mockUser._id, mockReq.body.article);
          expect(mockRes.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200);
          expect(mockRes.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            article: mockUpdatedArticle
          });
          expect(mockNext).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
      });
    });
```